# Can't post Chinese characters to my search form

Tags: html, forms, post, character-encoding, cjk

I'm having a bit of trouble posting chinese characters to a search form. It works great on localhost but not on my website.

The search input is this: 假发

The resulting url on localhost: 
http://search.taobao.com/search?commend=all&isnew=2&q=%BC%D9%B7%A2&source=search1

The resulting url on the website:
StackOverflow actually encode's it,the encode result is different though, thing is that on the website instead of q=%BC%D9%B7%A2 I get q=假发 in the url itself.
http://search.taobao.com/search?commend=all&isnew=2&q=%E5%81%87%E5%8F%91&source=search1

You can see that it actually inserts the chinese characters into the query. I have no idea why this works differently on lcoahost and on a live site. The character encoding is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=GB18030" />
```

But I tried UTF-8 as well, no changes.

here's the html of my form. The search query goes to the second input box. THe first one's for transaltion, which works fine. Not sure what's the deal and whether I have to encode the characters or not and why does it work on localhost???
Thanks in advance!

```
 <div class="search-box">
 <form id="search" name="search" action="http://search1.taobao.com/browse/search_auction.htm?at_topsearch=1" method="post" target="_blank">
 <div class="search-form">
 <span class="search-q">
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" accesskey="s" name="q" id="q" value="Translate and Find" style="width: 160px; font-family: Arial;" size="20" />
 </span>
 <button id="DoSearch" type="submit" style="font-weight: bold; font-family:Arial; color: #333; width: 165px;">
 Taobao Search</button>
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="at_topsearch" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="f" value="D9_5_1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="promote" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="isnew" value="2" />
 <input type="hidden" name="atype" value="b" />
 <input type="hidden" name="commend" value="all" />
 <input type="hidden" name="search_type" value="auction" />
 <input type="hidden" name="user_action" value="initiative" />
 <input type="hidden" name="ssid" value="s1-e" />
 </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `accept-charset="GB18030"` to your form tag. My guess is that your local server leaves the encoding up to the form (XAMPP does this for example), and the live server forces an encoding on the information.

If that doesn't work and you can use PHP to force an encoding on the submitted information. Or if you have the ability to modify server settings you can change the encoding.... But the PHP option is a million times simpler.

Comment: accept-charset="GB18030" did the trick, I can't believe it. I tried this before but with a different charset, thanks so much! I wish I could vote your answer up, but I don't have the needed rep! Cheers!!!